# Загрузка файла по сети - Java heap space

Tags: java, java-ee

При копировании файла jdk загоняет его полностью в память. Код:

```
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    URL urlSt = new URL(urlString);
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlSt.openConnection();
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);

    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
    conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Long.toString(fileSize));
    OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len = 0;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) >0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
```

В интернете, нашел некоторые варианты решения, но они не помогли, а только начали еще новые, соответствующие им, екзепшины выкидывать.

```
    conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode();
    conn.setChunkedStreamingMode();
```

ПРИМЕР: 
при использовании второго блока получаю вот это

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fixed length streaming mode set
```

если

```
fileSize=1,7Гб
setFixedLengthStreamingMode(fileSize) 
setChunkedStreamingMode(1024)
```

При тестировании использовались такие данные:

- 800мб - ОЗУ: 1024Мб = Java heap space;
- 970Мб - ОЗУ: 2024 = Ок;
- 1.7Гб - ОЗУ: 6144Мб = Ок;
- 4.1Гб - ОЗУ: 6144Мб = Java heap space;

ВОПРОС: как оправить большой файл и не получить екзепшн.

Comment: Так не загоняйте его в память или что вам нужно?

Comment: BigTows - Ваш ответ. нужно пометить как единственно верный. и больше никогда не задавать вопросы...

 D-side - сейчас я немного подкорректирую вопрос с указанием размеров ф-в с которыми проводились тесты

Comment: Попробуйте обернуть и input и output в BufferInputStream и BufferOutputStream. А так же добавьте метод [flush](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html#flush()), а то вы просто записываете в исходящий поток, но отправляете только в close.

Comment: @BigTows - в данный момент при отправке...

Comment: В следующий раз используйте @, чтобы вызвать кого-то. За данные спасибо. А какие конкретно ошибки возникают при применении решений из нижнего блока (режимы потоковой передачи)?

Comment: @D-side при использовании второго блока получаю вот это **`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fixed length streaming mode set`** если `setFixedLengthStreamingMode(fileSize)` `setChunkedStreamingMode(1024)` , а **fileSize=1791259521Kb**

Comment: И куда именно вы добавляли описанные строчки?

Comment: @D-side добавлял до While() а в while() вкидывал out.flush()

Comment: @Alex а вы документацию читали? "This method must be called **before the URLConnection is connected.**"

Comment: @D-side читал. и если я правильно понимаю, то коннект происходит вот в этой строке `conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlSt.openConnection();` но если перед ним вызвать `setFixedLengthStreamingMode(fileSize) или 
setChunkedStreamingMode(1024)` то получим Exception (по-моему NullPointer), в общем оно будет ругаться на NULL. А если выбросить `setChunkedStreamingMode(1024)` и оставить вот так 
`
...
conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlSt.openConnection();
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
setFixedLengthStreamingMode(fileSize)
...
`
и не забыть про flush() - должно работать

Comment: Вы можете обновить вопрос, приложив все детали самой последней ошибки. Пока ответов нет, от этого никакого вреда. Не надо воевать с ограничениями комментариев :)

Comment: @D-side но у меня не было еще возможности нормально протестировать данную ситуацию, как протестирую на файле более 4Гб или хоть -Xmx укажу. (запускал на 1.7Гб но без указания -Xmx). Как протестирую отпишусь.

Answer (score 0):

Правильм ответом оказались все теже вышеупомянутые методы. вот код.

```
HttpURLConnection conn = null;
URL urlSt = new URL(urlString);
conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlSt.openConnection();
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
// именно эта строка, в этом месте
conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(fileSize)

conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Long.toString(fileSize));
OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(fileName);
byte[] buf = new byte[102400];
int len = 0;
while ((len = in.read(buf)) >0) {
    out.write(buf, 0, len);
    out.flush();
}
in.close();
out.close();
```

Все работает как надо.

Тестировал с такими данными:

- Data: 1.7Гб; ОЗУ(-xmx): 512Мб = Ок;